# Javascript AJAX No-Access-Control-Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

So my code I was working on literally stopped over night. I am making a POST call to a REST API.  I ran into this problem yesterday and fixed it by installing the extention into chrome to add the headers automatically. However now that hasn't worked.  I have been reading all of the blogs on stack this morning as there have been a lot of people who have had this error but I can't seem to get mine to work.  Here is what i was using

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/?hapikey=demo",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: JSON.stringify(testContact),
                        success: function(result) {console.log(result);}

                    });
```

This morning I tried adding

```
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
```

I have tried many other things but nothing seems to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I can also get the call to work in PostMan still so I now the call is still valid.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the network tab in your developers tool to see how it's actually sent?. Also, apart from PostMan have you tried with other browsers?

Comment: I tried with Edge and got the same result

Comment: Request URL:https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/hapikey=demo
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:204 No Content
Remote Address:104.85.63.85:443
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:false
Allow:OPTIONS,POST
Connection:keep-alive
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, access-control-allow-origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.hubapi.com
Origin:file://

Comment: Ok. So try comparing what headers are sent between PostMan and other browsers.

Comment: The interesting thing i see above is the No conent with the status code 204

Comment: I don't have to use any headers in PostMan

Comment: Ok. So lets step back a bit. Are you trying to create a contact?

Comment: yes I am. I had this working as well yesterday with the above code which is the frustrating part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110016/discussion-between-hyperd-and-peter3).